# Is there a great way to get the current date in node that does not depend on the user's local machine date and time?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have written a blocking user system in node.js. I'm using nodejs, mongodb as data base and mongoose, expressjs and Reactjs.

I have successfully written the blocking logic and unblocking logic. I used mongoose $currentdate feature which fetches the currentdate but uses the current date of the local machine.
I simply said if expiryDate === currentdate, user should be unblocked.
I also tried to use Javascript to get the current date and it uses the local machine date and time.

Why I feel this isn't right is because the user's date and time maybe wrong. I tried this out by setting a wrong date on my local machine and the Javascript date system was setting a wrong date for me as well. This will surely make a mess of the unblocking logic.

If I write my logic using this, it can be dangerous since I do not have control over the user's local machine date and time settings.

Is there really a better way to get this done? I will be deploying the application to be hosted online in Amazon ec2 or haroku. This is part of my learning process actually. Wanted to know how this really work.
How do applications that use billing methods track my days? For instance, if I start a subscription today and the subscription lasts for 7 days, no matter the current state of my local machine date and time, the subscription will surely expire on the 7th day.
How can I achieve this? I would like the expiry logic to be independent of the user's local machine date and time.
Any npm package that can do this or best way to go about this?

Comment: Are you running a billing database on user's machines? Normally validation like this is done completely server side, where you control the machines.

Comment: Is this some kind of offline desktop or enterprise intranet software with no centralized backend?

Comment: Actually, it will be hosted online. I am planning to use Amazon ec2 to host it or haroku. Maybe I don't understand properly how system like this should work. Does it mean that if I use the current date system in Javascript, when hosted online, date and time will not depend on the user's local machine date and time?

Comment: Using `Date` will always depend on the local machine. But it depends on *where* that code runs - if it runs on a user's machine, you'd get the user's date. If it runs on the server, then you'd get the server date.

Comment: Oh, thanks for this feedback. That means once I deploy the code to the host such as Amazon, the Date system will come from that host provider? Is this correct?

Comment: You already know that you are getting datetime from the current machine. So if your server is running on an AWS machine somewhere, you that machine's time. Never trust data like that from a client.

Comment: As simple as this sounded, I didn't really understand it until you explained. Thank you very much. You, I didn't really think about that fact that since my codes currently sit in my machine windows environment, that when deployed to another system such as the Amazon macine, it will pick that environment :). I never thought about it this way.

Comment: Date/Time values in Javascript are based on **Milli**seconds after `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`, so `expiryDate === currentdate` may fail even if it runs on the same machine. Better set expiryDate like `expiryDate >= currentdate + 1000 *60*60` which will expire in 1 hour, for example.

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks, will check out this suggestion.

Comment: "*That means once I deploy the code to the host such as Amazon, the Date system will come from that host provider? Is this correct?*" depends - is it frontend code or backend code? Is it something you serve to the user - then it's frontend. It also means it runs on the user's machine and uses the local time for that machine. If it's backend code then it will run on the server and will use the server time. It's not totally clear to me *which* code you're talking about.

Comment: Okay, here is what I actually want to achieve. I created an admin and there are users. The admin can block a user from performing any function on the site until the expiry date. So, I created a route in my node to handle the blocking action by the admin. Only the admin can access this route. To block a user, the admin will set up the block date and expiry date. These dates are captured from reactjs calendar input and saved on the database. To unblock the user automatically, I setup a schedule task to unblock user once expiry date is less than or equal to current date.

Comment: While blockDate and expiryDate will be provided via the user who is the admin using reactjs calender, the currentDate is auto-generated using mongoose $currentDate method. So, in my database, I have blockDate, expiryDate and currentDate saved. The logic then compares the expiryDate with currentDate to know if a user will be unblocked or not. The task checks the database every 12 hours. So, I wanted to know when I deploy this application, will these dates be determined by my admin local machine or the network where I deployed my backend and frontend codes?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to depend on the system date, you have to use NTP (Network Time Protocol)

To use NTP in your node script, you can use an NTP module, one of these for example:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ntp-time
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ntp-time-sync
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ntp-client